# Why is my routing handler not being called when navigating between pages?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to implement authorization into my routing but the handler function is not being called when I navigate to the page from another page in the application.

```
valkyrie.get('/units/:unit', function(){console.log('test')});
```

When I navigate to a `units` page using the url, it works as expected and `test` is logged.

Comment: You'll need to show us how you are trying to navigate to this route

Comment: I have a link on the home page with an href that points to the suffix of the url like so:  <a href="units/57f6e36f81eecff06f52d90e" class="ng-binding">C7 ACERT</a>

Comment: so if you navigate to the path, by pasting in the `units/57f6e36f81eecff06f52d90e`, it works? but if you hit the link on a page, it doesn't?  Do you get any errors or anything? Or is the link resolving to a different page or anything?

Comment: The link resolves to the correct page either way, but when pasted the function does get called and when navigated it doesn't